# How to trigger Postman GET request with body like cURL -XGET -d'{"query": "aaa"}'

Tags: curl, get, postman

Is there any workaround to put body (JSON) to the **GET** request in Postman (the body button is disabled in GET mode)?
The example cURL request (AFAIK this is ES request what can be substituted by POST  - but I have external application what accepting only GET):

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/_search?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
    "query": {
        "query_string" : {
            "default_field" : "content",
            "query" : "this AND that OR thus"
        }
    }
}
'
```

Comment: There is no way to do it :(

Answer (score 0):

According to discussion on github 
https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/131
it is not possible.
But there is a hope in last comment:

> A new Node.js based networking stack will be available soon that will help us add bodies for GET calls.

Answer (score 0):

According to the same [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/131) ability to send requests with a body for any HTTP method was introduced in 6.5.2.

> Postman does allow setting the payload (body) with requests having any method (including GET)
> Please update to the latest version. This was released with version 6.5.0

Please refer to [Postman Public Roadmap](https://trello.com/c/9BkNcrlL/77-app-652-custom-request-methods-and-get-method-with-body) for more details.